# Are Banach manifolds metrizable?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, banach-spaces

Consider a manifold $M$ locally modelled on a Banach space $E$ (infinite dimensional)

> Can  $M$  be given a metric (that induces the given topology) and if the answer is positive, which assumptions are usually made to make it complete?

I am not talking about Riemannian metric, just ordinary metrics $d:M\times M \to [0,+\infty)$.

Comment: You can define a complete metric on every set (for example the discrete one). But do you want a metric that induces the given topology?

Comment: @MaoWao, yes please.

Comment: Then you should give the precise definition of Banach manifold you are using.

Comment: @MaoWao, the definition is standard, you can find it for example in Lang's book (introduction to differentiable manifolds) or wikipedia. Essentially it is just a like manifold  just that locally is modelled on a Banach space $E$ instead of $R^n$ with smooth transition  functions. 
Depending on $E$ it has a partition function or not, it can admit a strong Riemannian metric or a weak one on its tangent bundle and so on. 
But this question concerns whether it is a topological metric space; the answer will depend (probably) on $E$. 
You can assume it is Hausdorff it that is what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may be found in Palais "Homotopy theory of infinite dimensional manifolds", indeed it follows from  Theorem 1 that **a (T2) Banach manifold is metrizable iff it is paracompact** (indeed any Banach manifold is locally metrizable being modelled on a metric space).
Moreover it follows from Theorem 3 that **any paracompact (T2) Banach manifold admits a complete metric.**

(T2 = Hausdorff)